# Batch Findstr in loop error

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have this command from this [source](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-files-in-a-folder-containing-specified-string-and-move-those-files-to-another-folder-using-command-line-tools-under-Windows-7).

```
@for /r %a in (*.txt) do @findstr /m /s  /i "94272000-9 96717620-6 96678770-8 96814370-0 76004976-K 76008306-2 76085254-6 76170761-2 96635700-2 96588230-2" %a > nul && move "%~fa" C:\NewDir
```

It works (or at least does what I expect) when I execute from command line, but when I put it in a loop I get the following error:

```
batch parameters invalid: "%~fa" C:\NewDir
bad syntax
```

This is full code now with recommendations from @Ken White and @SomethingDark, now the batch file crashes after a while.

```
@echo off
cls
:start
@for /r %%a in (*.txt) do @findstr /m /s  /i "94272000-9 96717620-6 96678770-8 96814370-0 76004976-K 76008306-2 76085254-6 76170761-2 96635700-2 96588230-2" %%a > nul && move "%%~fa" C:\AES
goto start
```

Comment: How do you "put it in a loop"?

Comment: `@echo off
cls
:start
(COMMAND HERE)
goto start`

Comment: As your question says "when I put it in a loop", clearly you need to include the code where you try to *put it in a loop*. Please [edit] your question to add it there, where it can clearly be seen, instead of adding it in a comment.

Comment: are you trying to execute this through batch file?

Comment: If you're trying to run this in a batch file, you need to use `%%` instead of `%` for both occurrences of `%` in your code. If you're running this inside of another `for` loop, you need to make sure that you aren't using `%a` for both loops.

Comment: Use `move "%%~fa" C:\NewDir`

Comment: after modifications the applications crashes, but i get no errors.